# Tracing in Pre-Literacy/Childcare to Teach Writing Controversy

Tags: writing, writing-system-choice

Teaching writing through letter tracing prompts in childcare/early childhood seems to be quite a controversial topic.
I thought the use of tracing prompts with either dashes, faded or outlined letters was quite a universally accepted practice. Little did I know that this topic can generate fierce belief with many childcare centres vehemently opposed to children using tracing in learning letters in any form. Free writing and copying practices being the paramount form of teaching.

I understand that there are strong arguments against tracing. Tracing prompts with dashes are confusing and distract children. Many children trace over the dashes and not over the whole letter, discouraging good strokes and muscle memory. This blog by Dr Jenni Jacobs argues quite strongly against tracing -
https://learningprofessor.com/to-trace-or-not-to-trace/

However, there are handwriting programs such as by Professor Steve Graham from Vanderbilt that incorporates tracing practice with great outcomes.

https://peabody.vanderbilt.edu/departments/sped/research/casl_-_center_on_accelerating_student_learning.php

The research on this topic seems very mixed, and I am keen to hear from the expertise of this StackExchange with much gratitude.